# Can't bind data from web api to select option in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind some data to a select option in Angular 6, I am using *NgFor for this: The Json data structure is as follows:

```
{  
   "addresses":[  
      {  
         "address":"xxxxxxx",
         "address_line1":"None",
         "address_line2":"None",
         "address_line3":"",
         "billing":false,
         "id":79,
         "name":"xxxxx",
         "phone_number":null,
         "postal_code":"xxxxx",
         "town":"xxxxx"
      },
   ]
}
```

So to bind this into my select option I am doing:

```
<option value="null" disabled="true" [selected]="true">Select your option</option>
<option *ngFor="let item of address" [value]="item">
    {{item.address}}
</option>
```

Ts file to get data:

```
customerAddress = []; 

private getCustomerAddress() {
    this.service.getCustomerAddress(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('Customer address data is received');
      this.customerAddress = data;
    })
  }
```

Service linked to this:

```
  getCustomerAddress(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.customerAddressApiUrl + "/" + customerId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

There is no data being displayed in the select option? But data is fine in the console.log.

Comment: set value to `[value]="item.id"`

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Have pasted the correct code because you should loop on customerAddress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of customerAddress.addresses" [value]="item">
    {{item.address}}
</option>
```

Comment: That gives this error: Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: That worked thanks, although My placeholder has disappeared now?

Comment: That did not work unfortunately, it appears for 1 sec and then goes

Comment: try <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>

Comment: for non string values use [ngValue] instead of [value] as value will not work with complex objects and you will lost type in case of numeric values.

Answer (score -2):

The name of the array that your are browsing is `customerAddress` and not `adresses`